# Tree-like matches in regex with a fixed chain

Tags: regex, tree, fixed, chain

i have a very specific task to achieve with a single regex.
Here's the pattern of the text i have to extract the data from (note i'm parsing HTML-like code, stored in an immutable file) :

```
<tr>
<td > <a ><img /></a>
</td>
<td > <a ><span >RootData</span></a>
</td>
<td > Data1.1
</td>
<td > <a ><img /></a>
</td>
<td > <a ><span >Data1.2</span></a>
</td>
<td > &#160;
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td > Data2.1
</td>
<td > <a ><img /></a>
</td>
<td > <a ><span >Data2.2</span></a>
</td>
<td > &#160;
</td></tr>
...
```

First there's a root contained inside the first "tr". Still inside this one, there's some datq (Data1.1 and Data1.2) to extract.
Then comes a finite number of "tr" block each containing data to extract.
I'd like the matches to be like this :

- match 1 : 'RootData' 'Data1.1' 'Data1.2'
- match 2 : 'RootData' 'Data2.1' 'Data2.2'
- etc

So far i see what to do with 2 regex and 2 loops (like 1 searching for the Root, and the other to find all datas from this root) but i'd like it to be in a single regex.

If some of you already encountered that and could help, that'd be nice :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is impossible to do with just regex since you need two matches that start at the same location.

Comment: It is only possible if you use a regex engine like the one provided in .net languages or the regex module in python. Anyway, using regex to extract data from xml/html is not the good way. Use a parser to extract data, and then build the data structure (array, list, object ...) you need.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you'd like to have a single regular expression provide more than one match for the same input. Regular expressions do not work that way, and are probably just not the right tool for the problem you're trying to solve.